# How to load data from jqgrid using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

Initially I have create one one json message and hold it in a variable then trying to load this data in grid which works fine.Theni tried uisng JSON but getting only Loading message.
 I dont know what is wrong I have done. When check in `firebug` I can see json message comming from server.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
       <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"></script>
       <script src="scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>    
       <script src="scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>hey</h1>
      <table id="list"></table>
    </body>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "/xyz/filteredUsersAsJson",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Username", "User Type", "Full Name", "Telephone", "Email", "Region","Action"],
        colModel: [
        { name: "UserName", width: 55 },
        { name: "UserType", width: 90 },
        { name: "FullName", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "Contact", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "Email", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "Region", width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: "", width: 150 }
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "UserName",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        width: 940,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        multiselect: true,
        toppager: true,
        gridview: true,
        loadui:'block',
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Users",
        jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "UserName",
        cell: "",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        }
        });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

**json message:**

```
{
"page":"1",
   "total":2,
   "records":"13", 
   "rows": [{"UserName":"achauhan","UserType":"1","FullName":"1","Contact":"1","Email":"1","Region":"1"},
            {"UserName":"amnu","UserType":"2","FullName":"2","Contact":"2","Email":"2","Region":"1"},
            {"UserName":"frt","UserType":"3","FullName":"3","Contact":"3","Email":"3","Region":"1"},
            {"UserName":"sdsds","UserType":"4","FullName":"4","Contact":"4","Email":"4","Region":"1"},
            {"UserName":"sdsd","UserType":"5","FullName":"5","Contact":"5","Email":"5","Region":"1"}] 
}
```

Comment: To solve the problem you need just remove `jsonReader` which you use or replace it to `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "UserName"}`. The next problem: **`name: ""` is wrong**. You have to specify *any* non-empty `name`. For example `name: "Action"`. If you don't implemented *server side paging, sorting and filtering of data* I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true`. In the case the server can return *all* data at once, `datatype` will be change to `"local"` by jqGrid after first loading and the user can quickly sort, page and sort/filter the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You have some errors in jsonReader declaration, it must be like this:

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "UserName",
    cell: "",
    root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.records; }
}
```

I have tested, it works.

-

**Original anwser**

> How to load data from jqgrid using **local data**

If you want to use **local data**, you have to replace:

1. `url: "/xyz/filteredUsersAsJson", datatype: "json", mtype: "GET"`
   **with** `datatype: "local", data: yourVariableWithLocalData`
2. `jsonReader` **with** `localReader`

Comment: I am able to load data from local ,Updated subject line

Comment: getting error on console : ReferenceError: rows is not defined 

`root: function (obj) { return obj,rows; },`

Comment: Yeah, just replace `obj,rows` with `obj.rows`. :D

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
$("#list").jqGrid
```

to

```
$("#jqgrid").jqGrid
```

Comment: sorry , it was typo ,still the problem exists.